CollectionView with header don't work on iphone with iOS v. 17.0+ in Xamarin.Forms
I use collectionView with headerTemplate and this work pretty on android and iOS, but when the iOS update was released, iPhones with iOS version v.17+ have an error which consists of strange pauses between subsequent controls on the list and the list shakes and strangely jumps by several items or blocks scrolling. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? On devices with older versions of iOS and Android, everything works fine. My sample code below.
 <CollectionView
    Grid.Row="1"
    Header="{Binding .}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
    RemainingItemsThreshold="0"
    RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadCommand}">
    <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame
                    CornerRadius="10" 
                    IsClippedToBounds="True" 
                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    HeightRequest="80"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Text="Welcome"
                            FontSize="15"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                            FontSize="15"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{Binding ItIsMessage}"
                    Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                <Image 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{Binding ItIsImsge}"
                    Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                <Label 
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Text="{Binding Date}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding ItIsImsge}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>


I see you use Binding in HeaderTemplate? Did you use grouped data in CollectionView?

@LiqunShen-MSFT this causes the same error

Have you tried  using .NET MAUI? Will it behave better?

I have big project and i can't migrate this to MAUI now, but it may work better there

Did it throw any error or just a performance issue?

There are no errors, just a performance problem, so it's hard for me to diagnose what could be wrong and why only with this version of the system. It looks as if from v. 17+ the heights were converted differently, which is why this problem occurs, but how to solve it? :D

Is it because you load too many items in CollectionView?  Have you tried Load data incrementally?

I use it. This is shown in the code above

the heights were converted differently,  Which height converts differently? By the way, as Xamarin will be end of support from May, it is recommended to migrate Xamarin app to MAUI

it is about concerns the heights of visible controls and those that are currently not visible

You may set a fixed value for Heights to see if it helps.
